# Renaming a duplicate file using count (python)

Tags: python, count

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, datetime
import os.path
import sys
import time
import shutil
import re
import itertools

today = datetime.date.today()
todaystr = today.isoformat()

if os.path.exists('/var/log/brd/' + todaystr) is False and os.path.isfile('/var/log/brd/brd.log') is True:
    os.mkdir('/var/log/brd/' + todaystr) 
    shutil.move('/var/log/brd/brd.log', '/var/log/brd/' + todaystr)
    print "Directory Created, Moved Log File" 
    sys.exit()

elif os.path.isfile('/var/log/brd/brd.log') is True and os.path.exists('/var/log/brd/'+todaystr) is True: 
    num_files = sum(1 for file in os.listdir('/var/log/brd/') if os.path.isfile('/var/log/brd/{}/brd.log'.format(todaystr,)))
    next_num = num_files + 1
    os.rename('/var/log/brd/brd.log', '/var/log/brd/' + todaystr + '/blackbird.log_{}'.format(next_num))
    print "Renaming Duplicate"
    sys.exit() 

else:
    print "No Duplicate Found"
    sys.exit()
```

My situation:
Everyday a new dir. is created. It moves the days .log file into the daily directory.
Now, if it moves the same .log file in I need to add a count to the end of the file name (1,2,3...).  I can do this in bash rather easily using date/minutes/seconds, but I need to figure out how to use the count eventually.

I'm pretty new to python scripting so any help is appreciated.

Ok... here is the updated code.  I'm just trying to get everything running before I start cleaning it up...

Now... it runs good.. moves the file.  If it is run again it adds the count to the end (ends up being 18????) then when it goes to move/rename again it just replaces the _18 file with the newer log...
Keep in mind this is my first python script I have ever wrote.

```
e.@IT-105-WS4:~$ touch /var/log/brd/brd.log
e@IT-1~$ python BBdirectory.py 
Renaming Duplicate
e@IT1:~$ ls /var/log/blackbird/2012-10-05
brd.log  brd.log_19
e@IT-1:~$
```

it repeats the above process never making a 20 21...

Comment: Why don't you just use `logrotate`?

Comment: Wow... i need work on updating this too

Answer (score 3):

My answer may not be particular with question,
It may be worthful if you look at logrotate utility in linux.
That will automatically rotate you log file and renaming is not the problem.
here is a good example of [logrotate](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-rotate-log-files/)

Pass it if not constructive to you.

Answer (score 2):

Just count the number of files in the dir with:

```
count = len(os.listdir(path))
```

Let's say there is one file in the dir already, then this will produce a string of name1:

```
new_name= "name%s.log" % count
```

If you want to write to a new file (which doesn't seem to be the case):

```
with open (outfile, 'w') as of:
    ...
```

If you just want to rename the file use [`os.rename`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename):

```
os.rename(source/old_name,destination/new_name)
```

Comment: Should be `%d` in `outfile =...`.

Comment: Why? It will be used as a string, so why not convert to a string with `%s`?

Comment: @larsvegas `%.` is the type of the variable to input in the string. You are right. Here `%s` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach (but not ultimately that robust) would be:

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil

num_files = sum(1 for fname in os.listdir('/path/to/log/dir/') if os.path.isfile(fname))
next_num = num_files + 1
shutil.move('/path/to/your/file/log.txt', '/path/to/log/dir/log.{}'.format(next_num)
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry it took so long to respond.  I am still trying to configure it with what I have.  I'm glad you saw the 'new to python scripting' part.

Comment: @user1719938 Okay - Maybe it would be best if you added the code you're running and this comment back to your original question...